# Heroku pricing dyno confusion

Tags: heroku

I'd like to buy a "Hobby" package on Heroku but I'm confused by the pricing. It says $7 per Dyno per month, but then it also says you pay for the fraction of actual processing time. So if I have a thousand 100ms requests a day thats just 50 minutes a month. So do I pay 7/(30*24*60)*50 dollars for that total?

What if I dont have a single request for a month at all? Do I still need to pay?

thank you

Edit: I meant minutes, even less then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your dyno runs 24*7 the whole month you have to pay 7$. 
If your dyno runs just one day in a month you pay 7/30 $. 
This is what "fraction of actual processing time" means.
So the Hobby Dyno won't cost more then 7$.

Comment: Hi! Thanks. I understand, but isnt the point of the whole deal is that the Dyno runs 24/7 as opposed to free dyno which stops for 6 hours each day?

Comment: Yes—in most cases you will leave it running 24x7x30. Sometimes (rarely at the low end) you might only run a dyno (as a background worker, or for a one-off task) for a short period and would hence pay *less* than $7. You won't pay more for that dyno type though.